# Read from file without blocking it from being deleted

Tags: c#, streamreader

I'm writing a windows service that reads from a file share on the network. Sometimes files are written to the file share and then deleted in very quick succession. Is there a way that I can read the file while also allowing the file to be deleted?

Basically I've got a filesystemwatcher watching the network path and then on the Created event for that directory I check the filepath and then try to read the file on a new thread. When the app that writes the file to the directory tries to delete it quickly, it gets IOException saying there's another process using the file. I didn't write the app on the network computer and don't want to interrupt its normal function

Here's my code

```
public async Task Copy(string src, string dest) {
    using (FileStream srcReader = File.Open(src, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    using (Stream destWriter = File.Create(dest)) {
       await srcReader.CopyToAsync(destWriter, cancelToken);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[FileShare has a `Delete` flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileshare?view=net-5.0#fields). So try this:

```cs
File.Open(
    src, 
    FileMode.Open, 
    FileAccess.Read, 
    FileShare.ReadWrite | FileShare.Delete
)
```